# Creating a plastic scallion whistle

Tags: filament-choice, plastic

Recently my uncle-in-law taught me to make a whistle using a scallion stem. You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmYjcHH1ChM) to see the process. Of course, the video shows making a whistle with an onion stem. But a scallion is also a plant and produces the same sound.

Since it rots after just hours, I'm wondering to make a plastic whistle with the same thickness and flexibility to produce the same sound (of course, one end is thinner, and the inner layers of scallion should be removed).

Which kind of plastic is better for this to be used in 3D printing? Can I also make holes in it to produce a flute?